# oracle obiee12 fro configexe eorror

Tags: oracle, obiee

please help me I install OBIEE12, RCU is success but I config in D:\OBIEE12C\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin

Click Config.exe is it eorror for add defualt service instance : Failed in running all the handlers during backing up of service instance

[image]

--for logfile of config.exe in obiee --

- *[2017-09-07T21:46:27.693-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] []
     [oracle.bi.bar.util.DomainIntrospectUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Obtained Singleton Data
     Directory as
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.709-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.util.serviceinstance.ServicesUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No associated application
     modules found for service instance.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceContext] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] modules.xml path is
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\metadata\modules\modules.xml
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully
     run preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.migration.webcat.WebcatMetadataManagerGenericPluginImpl
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully
     run createServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.migration.webcat.WebcatMetadataManagerGenericPluginImpl
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully
     run preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.migration.webcat.WebcatMetadataManagerGenericPluginImpl
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.771-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0]
     includeCredentails is empty. So, setting flag includeConnectionInfo
     as false.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.RpdMetadataManagerPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     createServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.RpdMetadataManagerPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.RpdMetadataManagerPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.JaznMetadataManagerGenericPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     createServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.JaznMetadataManagerGenericPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     preCreateServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.JaznMetadataManagerGenericPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.787-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.802-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.util.serviceinstance.ServicesUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Adding service owner weblogic
     to services.xml. 
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.818-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [BAR-00002] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Run of all the handlers
     finished successfully for create service instance of ssi
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.818-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removing the odl handler for
     the run.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.818-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Path from ODL Handler =
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bilogs\service_instances\ssi\metadata\si20170907_214627.log
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.818-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Path from ODL Handler =
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bilogs\service_instances\ssi\metadata\si20170907_214627.log
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.818-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Found odl handler logging to
     log file
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bilogs\service_instances\ssi\metadata\si20170907_214627.log
         [2017-09-07T21:46:27.834-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.util.ValidateFileTypeUtil] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Find file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.036-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Provided file
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi\bifoundation\samples\sampleapplite\SampleAppLite.bar
     is in correct bar format.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.036-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Metadata to be imported WEBCAT
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.036-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Metadata to be imported RPD
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.036-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Metadata to be imported JAZN
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.052-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.BarFileReader] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Extracting MANIFEST.MF from bar
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.052-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.BarFileReader] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Setting Module Name from BAR:
     oracle.bi.sampleapplite
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.068-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.BarFileReader] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Setting Module version from
     BAR: 12.2.1.0
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.068-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.BarFileReader] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No BAR Dependency found
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.114-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Taking backup
     of folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\content
     to folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\tmp\backupImportBar\content
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.130-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Taking backup of
     folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\datamodel
     to folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\tmp\backupImportBar\datamodel
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.130-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] File
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\authmodel\jazn\jazn-data.xml
     does not exists. So, there is no need to copy for backup.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.146-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Find environment
     variable BI_PRODUCT_HOME as
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node credstore.db
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node keystore.db
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Find the policy store node
     policystore.db
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node audit.db
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node trust
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node pdp.service
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node attribute
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node idstore.xml
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.161-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Removed the node
     idstore.loginmodule
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Created
     jps-config-temp.xml successfully
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Name of stripe obi
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] find java in system property
     java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre java.version
     = 1.8.0_144
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] java home for the run =
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] ORACLE_HOME :
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\bi
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] oracle_common location :
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.177-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Command to execute :-
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin\java -Xms1548m
     -Xmx2048m -cp C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.jps*;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.ldap*;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\rda\da\lib*;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.idm*;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.osdt*;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\oracle_common\modules\oracle.odl\ojdl.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\bi..\bi\lib\bi-bar.jar
     oracle.bi.bar.jazn.MigrateApplicationPolicyProcess
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin....\user_projects\domains\bi\config\fmwconfig\jps-config-temp.xml
     default policystoresourcecontext obi obi false 
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.271-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Error occurred during
     initialization of VM
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.272-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Could not reserve enough space
     for 2097152KB object heap
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.273-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.jazn.JaznUtils] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Exit value1
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.273-07:00] [bi] [ERROR] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Failed in migrateing
     policy store from stripe obi to file
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\tmp\backupImportBar\authmodel\backup\jazn-data.xml
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.273-07:00] [bi] [ERROR] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.ServiceInstanceFrameWorkImpl] [tid: 34]
     [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Error during import
     service
     instanceoracle.bi.bar.si.exception.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleException:
     Failed in migrateing policy store from stripe obi to file
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\tmp\backupImportBar\authmodel\backup\jazn-data.xml
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.273-07:00] [bi] [ERROR] [BAR-00010] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Failed in running all the
     handlers during backing up of service instance.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:28.351-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Service Instance retrieved from
     the environment is [[
          ServiceInstance : 
           [description = Default BI Service Instance
           key = ssi
           path = service_instances\ssi\metadata
           ]
         ]]
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Service Instance retrieved from
     the environment is [[
          ServiceInstance : 
           [description = Default BI Service Instance
           key = ssi
           path = service_instances\ssi\metadata
           ]
         ]]
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\content\catalog
     exits. So, deleting the folder.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\content\msgdb
     exits. So, deleting the folder.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.WebcatServiceInstanceHandler]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully
     run deleteServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.migration.webcat.WebcatMetadataManagerGenericPluginImpl
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\datamodel
     exits. So, deleting the folder.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\datamodel\customizations
     does not exits. So, deletion of folder is not required.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0]
     includeCredentails is empty. So, setting flag includeConnectionInfo
     as false.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.RpdServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Successfully run
     deleteServiceInstance for plugin
     oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.plugin.RpdMetadataManagerPlugin
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No warning
     messages found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.ServiceInstanceHandlerHelper]
     [tid: 34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] No log File
     found in the message list of status object.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.framework.handler.JaznServiceInstanceHandler] [tid:
     34] [ecid: 0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi\metadata\authmodel\jazn
     exits. So, deleting the folder.
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Run of all the handlers
     finished successfully. 
         [2017-09-07T21:46:30.925-07:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.bar.si.ServiceInstanceLifeCycleImpl] [tid: 34] [ecid:
     0000LtVlfMaFs10_zxl3iW1PgXry000004,0] Folder
     C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\service_instances\ssi
     exits. So, deleting the folder.
         *\

Comment: Have you looked into the log file ... ?

Comment: What OS are you trying to install the OBIEE software? Make sure you are installing in a certified system,

Comment: install OBIEE on windowserver 208r2

Comment: log file for config eorror  click Config.exe is it eorror for add defualt service instance : Failed in running all the handlers during backing up of service instance

Comment: please help me for problem config OBIEE eorror

Comment: You have a policy store migration error. There are a couple ways to address it - one) run a blank installation and then roll forward the catalog, RPD and the security store; or two) raise an SR with the Support.

Comment: I don't know , please example give me because i don't understand                **THANK YOU**